# Размеры окна калькулятора при открытии нескольких копий

Tags: windows, windows-10

Когда открываю встроенный калькулятор в windows 10, первая копия открывая нормальных размеров. Вот так. 

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего открываю вторую копию и уже она открывается вот таких размеров.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что это мелочь, но все же не совсем удобно. 

В параметрах нажимал кнопочку "**сбросить**" в дополнительных параметрах калькулятора, но это не помогает. 

Хочу сказать, что эта проблема у меня тянется уже со времен windwos 10 1511, и хочу заметить, что переустанавливал систему с форматированием системного раздела. Не знаю, у меня так или у всех... 
Это как то решается?